# SimpleXML PHP Cannot Create Object

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I am attempting to do what I think should be rather simple. I want to take a XML string from a text box and convert it into a SimpleXML object to parse, once I have the data in the SimpleXML object I will load it into a database (this part I have no issues with) for later use.

The code seems simple enough and my XML appears to be OK but I keep getting:

> [30-Dec-2014 16:48:15 UTC] Error parsing XML file : Input is not
>   proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE2 0x7A 0x7A 0x6F

Upload.php

```
<form action="parse.php" method="get">
<textarea name="XML" rows="20" cols="60">Delete this text and Paste XML string here... </textarea>
<br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Data">
</form>
```

Parse.php

```
<?php $myXMLData = $_GET["XML"]; 

$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);

?>
```

XML Text - As far as I can tell using W3Schools XML validation the format is OK.

```
<ksk date="2014-12-29" time="14:46">
<classes>
<c id="08" v="mage"/>
<c id="09" v="warlock"/>
<c id="00" v="unknown"/>
<c id="10" v="monk"/>
<c id="07" v="shaman"/>
<c id="06" v="deathknight"/>
<c id="05" v="priest"/>
<c id="04" v="rogue"/>
<c id="02" v="paladin"/>
<c id="03" v="hunter"/>
<c id="11" v="druid"/>
<c id="01" v="warrior"/>
</classes>
<users>
<u id="0011" n="Spâzzo-zul'jin" c="04"/>
<u id="001a" n="Txxstorm-zul'jin" c="01"/>
<u id="0007" n="Derider-zul'jin" c="09"/>
<u id="0019" n="Pseven-zul'jin" c="07"/>
<u id="0009" n="Papadruid-zul'jin" c="11"/>
<u id="0014" n="Ellenplague-zul'jin" c="06"/>
<u id="0017" n="Nito-zul'jin" c="06"/>
<u id="0003" n="Valdarixie-zul'jin" c="10"/>
<u id="0012" n="Tekvar-zul'jin" c="11"/>
<u id="0015" n="Kangdandy-zul'jin" c="03"/>
<u id="0013" n="Tissie-zul'jin" c="02"/>
<u id="0016" n="Moonfrosty-zul'jin" c="08"/>
<u id="0002" n="Staysha-zul'jin" c="11"/>
<u id="000a" n="Pogozorro-zul'jin" c="10"/>
<u id="0004" n="Shauleata-zul'jin" c="01"/>
<u id="0001" n="Blackòut-zul'jin" c="02"/>
</users>
<lists>
<list id="141215a9edbda8" n="MaS Priority">
<u id="0011"/>
<u id="001a"/>
<u id="0007"/>
<u id="0019"/>
<u id="0009"/>
<u id="0014"/>
<u id="0017"/>
<u id="0003"/>
<u id="0012"/>
<u id="0015"/>
<u id="0013"/>
<u id="0016"/>
<u id="0002"/>
<u id="000a"/>
<u id="0004"/>
<u id="0001"/>
</list>
<list id="141215b1c46373" n="MaS Raid">
<u id="0013"/>
<u id="0002"/>
<u id="0016"/>
<u id="0007"/>
<u id="0015"/>
<u id="0001"/>
<u id="0003"/>
<u id="0017"/>
<u id="0014"/>
<u id="0019"/>
<u id="0012"/>
<u id="001a"/>
<u id="0011"/>
<u id="000a"/>
<u id="0004"/>
<u id="0009"/>
</list>
</lists>
</ksk>
```

Any suggestions or pointers on how best to parse this XML and get it into the database

Comment: Have you tried actually inspecting/outputting the error with `libxml_get_errors()` rather than just your `"Error: Cannot create object"` string literal? Also, my guess is your issue is that you're missing the xml declaration: `<?xml ... ?>`

Comment: Can you provide `var_dump($myXMLData)` output in your question? Also, why use GET here instead of POST? POST would seem more appropriate.

Comment: Edited post with info form error log

Comment: var_dump($myXMLData) gives string(1725) " "

Comment: Also of note I did change the Get to Post

Comment: See as well: [Character Encoding and HTML Forms](http://www.intertwingly.net/blog/2004/04/15/Character-Encoding-and-HTML-Forms) (you might want to use UTF-8 here, all browsers do support it)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting everyone's time, the issue appears to be the special characters in a few of the names. I am very new to this and was not sure where to start digging.